# Change Location of Apt-Get archive files ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I want to change the location of archive files which gets saved when I say `sudo apt-get install <packageName>`. By default they are getting saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
sudo ln -s /your/desired/folder /var/cache/apt/archives
```

(Make sure to move `/var/cache/apt/archives` to `/your/desired/folder` before creating the symbolic link)